# matlab iterative filenames for saving

Tags: string, matlab, file-io, filenames, save

this question about matlab:
i'm running a loop and each iteration a new set of data is produced, and I want it to be saved  in a new file each time. I also overwrite old files by changing the name. Looks like this:

```
name_each_iter = strrep(some_source,'.string.mat','string_new.(j).mat')
```

and what I#m struggling here is the iteration so that I obtain files:
...string_new.1.mat
...string_new.2.mat
etc.

I was trying with various combination of () [] {} as well as 'string_new.'j'.mat' (which gave syntax error)

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For creating a name based of an already existing file, you can use [regexp](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/regexp.html) to detect the '_new.(number).mat' and change the string depending on what regexp finds:

```
original_filename = 'data.string.mat';
im = regexp(original_filename,'_new.\d+.mat')
if isempty(im) % original file, no _new.(j) detected
    newname = [original_filename(1:end-4) '_new.1.mat'];
else
    num = str2double(original_filename(im(end)+5:end-4));
    newname = sprintf('%s_new.%d.mat',original_filename(1:im(end)-1),num+1);
end
```

This does exactly that, and produces:

```
    data.string_new.1.mat
    data.string_new.2.mat
    data.string_new.3.mat
    ...

    data.string_new.9.mat
    data.string_new.10.mat
    data.string_new.11.mat
```

when iterating the above function, starting with 'data.string.mat'

Comment: thanks, and now I found the simpliest possible solution :) :
name_each_iter = strrep(some_source,'.string.mat',['string_new.' num2str(j) '.mat'])
so adding square brackets is enough in this case to iterate.

Answer (score 6):

Strings are just vectors of characters. So if you want to iteratively create filenames here's an example of how you would do it:

```
for j = 1:10,
   filename = ['string_new.' num2str(j) '.mat'];
   disp(filename)
end
```

The above code will create the following output:

```
string_new.1.mat
string_new.2.mat
string_new.3.mat
string_new.4.mat
string_new.5.mat
string_new.6.mat
string_new.7.mat
string_new.8.mat
string_new.9.mat
string_new.10.mat
```

Comment: it works very well with saving a new file, but for me doesn't in case of overwriting so when I use strrep with 'num2str(j)'. Do I omit something?

Answer (score 5):

You could also generate all file names in advance using NUM2STR:

```
>> filenames = cellstr(num2str((1:10)','string_new.%02d.mat'))

filenames = 
    'string_new.01.mat'
    'string_new.02.mat'
    'string_new.03.mat'
    'string_new.04.mat'
    'string_new.05.mat'
    'string_new.06.mat'
    'string_new.07.mat'
    'string_new.08.mat'
    'string_new.09.mat'
    'string_new.10.mat'
```

Now access the cell array contents as `filenames{i}` in each iteration

Answer (score 3):

[sprintf](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) is very useful for this:

```
for ii=5:12
    filename = sprintf('data_%02d.mat',ii)
end
```

this assigns the following strings to `filename`:

```
    data_05.mat
    data_06.mat
    data_07.mat
    data_08.mat
    data_09.mat
    data_10.mat
    data_11.mat
    data_12.mat
```

notice the zero padding. sprintf in general is useful if you want parameterized formatted strings.

Comment: thanks! another great idea. but how to combine it with replacing string parts for already existing names?

Comment: always save your files in this way, so you can reconstruct the filename easily.

Comment: true, but you may have access to a ready structure of files which you only overwrite by replacing some name part while saving. That is why I stick to strrep, because I want to search for a certain string in the filename without knowing these names at all.