# What orders to save a file by string AND variable? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, naming

I have a for loop that goes through 7 elements in an array and does an operation, and gets a 'work' (name of variable) variable. I want to save this work variable in the form of 'work_#ofexperiment' (experiments 1 through 7)

So I have experiment 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

And an array [stuff1,stuff2,stuff3,stuff4,stuff5,stuff6,stuff7];

for i=1:7

do stuff 
 work = something
 save work based on the order of i and name it work_experiment#

save('work_%s',work,experiment(i)) is not working

Comment: You're almost there... you need to use `sprintf` instead of directly adding the string to `save`. I'm sure there is a duplicate of this somewhere... looking...

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673674/matlab-iterative-filenames-for-saving

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass names of variables as strings to the save function.

```
save(sprintf('work_%d',i), 'work', 'experiment')
```

With save function you cannot do partial saving like experiment(i). Once saved you can partially update the mat file using matfile function. (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.matfile-class.html).

```
matObj = matfile('work_%s')
matObj.Properties.Writable = true
matObj.experiment(i) = newValue;
```