# Saving figure without providing filename

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have been looking this up but I couldn't find it. What I want is the following: every time I run "saveas/print/whatever", I want MATLAB to save my current plot to a different file, no matter how it is called. Ex: figure1, figure2, etc without providing a filename.

Can this be done without rewriting?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. See the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11673674/matlab-iterative-filenames-for-saving)

Comment: Guys, this is not a duplicate: the question is whether plots can be saved without providing a filename (given that there is a default filename?)

Comment: @Peter: I'm pretty sure you *have* to provide a file name for any kind of command when saving a figure (`print`, `saveas`, `savefig`, etc.). Your only option to save you effort is to automate the creation of the filename as illustrated in the linked question.

Comment: Alright, thanks! :)